# How to change default "Page Not Found" window (template) in TYPO3 v6.2.x

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I made a website with TYPO3 v6.2.x. When the `url` goes wrong it shows the default typo3 "page not found" template(window). Its shown below.

[image: Default Error Page]

I need to change it. So that I want to add custom text or images to show the error page as my style(without typo3 logo and text) .

How is it possible??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using the setting `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'][FE][pageNotFound_handling]`. You can see a short documentation of it in the TYPO3 install tool under "All configuration", and you can also modify its value there.

**EDIT**

For simple understanding(people like me :))

1.select `install` tool from left main panel

2.select `All configuration` from it

3.Select `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']`

4.Add new template path to `[FE][pageNotFound_handling]`.

Finished. :)

Comment: Can you please explain it little more detail? The method fro applying it.